# How to install xorg-x11-fonts

Tags: 11.04, xorg, fonts

I need to install `xorg-x11-fonts`. I was searching in Google how to install them but couldn't really find anything. I need it for Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `xorg-x11-fonts` package in Ubuntu.  There is a package by that name in Fedora, but rather than packaging up a bunch of fonts into a single package they are split up on Ubuntu in packages such as `xfonts-base`, `xfonts-100dpi`, `xfonts-75dpi`, `xfonts-cyrillic`, etc.

Some of these font packages are probably already installed on your system, but for the most part scalable outline fonts are preferred to these legacy bitmap fonts.

If there is a particular bitmap font you need to install, you can probably find it by searching for packages containing `xfonts` in their name.