# wkhtmltopdf displaying text as blocks

Tags: fonts, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

We're using wkhtmltopdf in a web project (nodejs/compoundjs). We've gotten it working how we wanted on our machines (using the `--use-xserver` switch). However, when I try to run this on our Ubuntu server 12.04 (without the ubuntu-desktop package), the PDF cannot use the  switch. When we disable the switch, the PDF displays any characters as blocks (image below).

How do I resolve this without installing ubuntu-desktop and running x server?

I've found [liberation fonts](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=722), which installing ttf-liberation and fonts-liberation did not help. And [urw-fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8680625/724591), but I have yet to find an Ubuntu equivalent.

[image: PDF Output]

**EDIT**: It just hit me, this doesn't matter if I'm on the server or not. On my development machine (Ubuntu 13.04 desktop), I can run the following, which produces the same blocks:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google1.pdf
```

While this prints out the pdf properly:

```
wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver http://google.com google2.pdf
```

My version of wkhtmltopdf is 0.12.0.

Comment: I've just learned that PhantomJS also supports capturing to PDF, if that helps at all.

Comment: @ændrük, Thanks for the suggestion. I've heard of it as well, but we've used wkhtmltopdf in other projects (.NET/Windows Server) and already have this implemented to how we like it.

Comment: is pango and freetype installed? they are essential to modern Linux text rendering

Answer (score 1):

In fact wkhtmltopdf on linux requires quite a lot of Xorg as mentioned on [the project page](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/):

> (Linux) No longer requires an XServer to be running (however the X11 client libs must be installed)

You should install the client libs as well.

Answer (score 0):

[This bug report](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=113) suggests that wkhtmltopdf just needs [whatever `xorg-x11-fonts` provides](https://askubuntu.com/q/72122/1859):

```
$ wajig list-installed xfonts
xfonts-base
xfonts-encodings
xfonts-mathml
xfonts-scalable
xfonts-utils
```

So try installing those. Note that you'll pull in several X dependencies, but [not the server itself](https://drupal.org/comment/890752#comment-890752).

Comment: I have all of these xfonts on my dev machine and it gives the same results. I'm looking into trying to find the correct xfonts package through the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PdfKit on Lambda, you will have to setup ENV variables as:

```
"FONT_CONFIG_PATH": '/opt/fonts/' 
"FONTCONFIG_FILE": '/opt/fonts/fonts.conf'
```

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486261/include-custom-fonts-in-aws-lambda

If this problem is in the local environment, a fresh installation of `wkhtmltopdf` must resolve this.