# How to install old-style X11 Fonts

Tags: xorg, fonts

For my work I need to test updates to an old Motif-era X-Windows application.

However, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not seem to include the old X Windows bitmap(?) fonts.  When the program starts I get the familiar "missing font" messages:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-adobe-times-medium-r-*-*-18-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-adobe-new century schoolbook-bold-r-*-*-24-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" to type FontStruct
... etc.
```

Without those exact fonts all the dialogue windows have different text with weird spacings & sizes.  My automated tests rely on the dialogue buttons being in the same place, and they now aren't.

Is there any way to install these old fonts?

I have already installed the packages:  `xfonts-100dpi` and `xfonts-75dpi`  (`xfonts-base` is installed by default), as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72122/how-to-install-xorg-x11-fonts).

EDIT: It's not `xfonts-traditional` either.

EDIT2: They're working now.  Maybe you have to re-generate the font-cache/index yourself, or at least logout/reboot.  I tried a whole bunch of stuff myself, so I'm not sure exactly what it was.